# How to implement server shut down

Tags: java, client-server

I've been looking at a clean way of implementing shut down logic for a server that I'm developing.

There are two approaches that I could take:

- Use Runtime.addShutdownHook() to gracefully handle shut down when Ctrl-C is issued.
- Listen to a designated shut down port (similar to what Tomcat does) and shut down when the appropriate command is received through that port.

The first approach is simple to implement but using Ctrl-C as the shut down mechanism doesn't seem elegant.
The second approach seems cleaner, but requires the overhead of configuring and listening to another port.

I would appreciate advice on this, particularly if you can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: What's wrong with defining a shutdown command to be received over the *existing* port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you have a choice ;)

Depending on how and where your server runs, and what kind of resources you use, you will need to implement a shutdown hook for the odd case where someone actually goes and ctrl+c's the whole thing (regardless of it being on the user manual or not)

On the other hand, and for regular usage, having a way to push a shutdown command seems like the best way to go. You might not need a dedicated port or command set, though; you might be able to include it into your normal, existing interface.

Comment: I would go for what @Miquel writes. You always want to send some sort of shutdown command for normal operations and another way for unexpected conditions, e.g. if the usual interface is not reachable.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, your application is receiving commands already, right? I mean, it has to have input somehow!. Why not just add an additional command for a shutdown?

Obviously you'll want some security around issuing the command, but it if you already have the code to perform the shutdown (whatever you would put in the hook) you can just put in the command.